# can't display "wrong pw"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this simple login page below ,

if I enter correct ID + pw -> success (which I want)

if I enter wrong ID -> wrong login (which I want)

But if I enter correct ID + wrong ID , I Want it to say wrong password.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["X"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
        }
    }

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (TextBox1.Text == dr.GetString(0) || TextBox2.Text == dr.GetString(1))
                    {
                            Session["x"] = TextBox1.Text;
                            Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
                    }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "wrong login";
                }
            }
        }

        cnn.Close();

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: How many users are recorded in your Employees table? This code has serious problems if you have more than one user registered

Comment: You should **never** display any message like "wrong password" or "wrong username". Always give a vague error message that says that the username or password is wrong. Otherwise you're giving an attacker the hint that the username is right, which you should never do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while this doesn't answer your question, I see a MAJOR security flaw with your logic. I think no matter what failure your users encounter, invalid username or invalid password, you should always display the same "invalid login" message.

If you have someone who is attempting to break into the system, once you validate that a user account exists (invalid password) they can then begin to crack that specific account's password using brute force.

Just something to think about.

Comment: Thanks for recommendations.

Comment: +1 for the security logic.  Just one more thing.  You cannot tell whether the u/p is incorrect, as there may be multiple users with the same password.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your logic wrongly here. the logic will be

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["X"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
        }
    }

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Employees", cnn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {

                if (TextBox1.Text.Trim() == dr.GetString(0) || TextBox2.Text.Trim()== dr.GetString(1))
                    {
                        if (TextBox2.Text.Trim()== dr.GetString(1))
                        {
                            Session["x"] = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
                            Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label2.Text = "wrong password";
                        }
                    }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "wrong login";
                }

        }

        cnn.Close();

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Register.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the firstname and the lastname from the database, but then check for the password against the lastname. I doubt that this field contains a valid password

A part from this logic error, you should use a WHERE clause in your statement to check if the user is present or not in the database.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Command with parameters that check if a user with the supplied credentials exists
    // If the user exists then just one record is returned from the datatable....
    string cmdText = "SELECT FirstName,LastName " + 
                     "FROM Employees " + 
                     "WHERE username=@uname and pass=@pwd";
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(.....))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cnn))
    {
         cnn.Open();
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox1.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", TextBox2.Text);
         using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
              // If the Read returns true then a user with the supplied credentials exists 
              // Only one record is returned, not the whole table and you don't need to 
              // compare every record against the text in the input boxes 
              if(reader.Read())
              {
                   Session["x"] = reader.GetString(0);
                   Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
              }
              else
              {
                   Label2.Text = "Invalid credentials";
              }
         }
     }
 }
```

Another point to keep in mind is the following. In the database you should not have a password in clear text. The correct way to store password is to store an hashed string corresponding to the password and then applying the hashing function to the user input and check for same hashed string in the database